# running NASM assembly gives a segfault

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, elf

I'm trying to make ELFs from scratch to better understand how they work. I tried this simple program:

```
mov eax,1
mov ebx,4
syscall
```

Which should simply exit with code 4, but when I assemble (`nasm test.asm -o asm.bin`) put it in the ELF and run it it doesn't work and it segfaults.
It could be a problem of the ELF, but I don't think so because I tried with the manual assembly of the tutorial I'm following and it works as expected.
The weird thing is that the assembly the tutorial I'm following uses (which is manually assembled) is different than the one nasm produces (for example, `mov rax,0` is encoded as `66 B8 00 00 00 00` by nasm where the tutorial encodes it as `B8 00 00 00 00`, without the leading `0x66`). As I said though, the tutorial's is working while the assembler's isn't. I've never used NASM before, so am I missing some assembler flags or something like that?

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?   Also, note that `syscall` is for 64 bit system calls but you prepare the system call as if you wanted to make a 32 bit system call (which uses `int 0x80`).  This is weird.  I can't tell you what the correct answer is as you have not specified the operating mode (32 or 64 bit) you are programming for.

Comment: i'm using 32 bits. as for syscall, thanks i didn't notice because when I compiled with `syscall` and `int 0x80` they both resulted in the same (not working) binary. now i tried what the first answer suggested me and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `66` byte indicates the issue; nasm is assembling in 16-bit mode by default, so `mov eax,1` requires an opcode size prefix (the `66` byte) to switch to a 32-bit operation. However, (I'm assuming) you're running this program in a 32/64-bit OS, which means the CPU is interpreting the prefix to switch to 16-bit; thus it sees the instruction as `66 B8 01 00`, aka `mov ax,1`; now the instruction pointer is misaligned, hence the crash.

The fix is to put a `bits 32` or `bits 64` (whichever is appropriate) directive at the top of your assembly file.